# In relation to Newtonian physics, can an object's movement still be affected by extreme temperature when in a vacuum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, velocity, vacuum

I'll try to keep it short:

Can an object (such as a ship or shuttle) be slowed by extreme temperature when in the vacuum of space, or is temperature irrelevant at that point due to the nature of a vacuum?

Comment: The temperature of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean extreme temperature due to a star closeby? Then sure. There is an effect called [radiation pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pressure). Photons carry momentum. The higher the temperature of the star, the higher the photon momentum. And this momentum can be transfered onto the ship if it's hit by the photon, thereby slowing it down (or speeding it up, depending on the direction of velocity of the ship.) This is how [Solar Sails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail) work. If your ship has a large area which can collect a lot of light and not a lot of mass, you can get it to very high velocities, just using radiation pressure.

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks!